# How can I make the project refactoring programmatically in Java?

Tags: android, refactoring

I have a template project that generates a signed APK using ant script , each APK should be uploaded to the market with different package name which requires refactoring the packages for the whole project, 
the problem that I was able to create the apk with new configuration each time but I need to add the refactoring, so all will work programmatically without any manual interaction.

Is there a good and clear example to do that?

Comment: Note that the "package" name in the application's `<manifest>` is *only* the unique ID of your application. It does not have to be related to any Java package/class in your app and can thus be chosen independently from the code. See for example [here](http://blog.javia.org/android-package-name/).

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard (now replaced by R8 compiler) could help you in refactoring. See Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code